# Understanding Metal usage with AVCaptureSession video output

Tags: objective-c, swift, avcapturesession, metal, cmsamplebufferref

I'm trying to understand what is the right way to manipulate Video output(`CMPixelBuffer`), using Metal.

As far as i understand there is `MTKView`.
Each `CMPixelBuffer`, from the video output, is being assigned to some what of `Metal Texture`. So the final preview is the from the `MTKView`?

When i see the final result on the screen, is it :

```
1)CMSampleBuffer->Metal->CMSampleBuffer
```

or

```
2)CMSampleBuffer->Metal->MTKView
```

Pretty confused. Can someone put things on spot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd encourage you to do this in two steps. First, get comfortable using Metal and `MTKView` to draw something, anything, to the screen. Second, after you know how to draw with Metal (create and encode to command buffers, present drawables, etc), you can apply the texture you generate from the `CMSampleBuffer` to a full-screen quad or whatever other geometry you want.

There's a camera capture sample by @McZonk available [here](https://github.com/McZonk/MetalCameraSample/blob/master/MetalCamera/GameViewController.m) that implements a simple example of this. It uses a two-plane YCbCr sample buffer, but if available, you can also request a BGRA formatted sample buffer that can then be converted into a single `MTLTexture` with `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` and sampled in a shader without further manual conversion.

Comment: Warrenm, i think i've found my mentor at the Metal field :) Thank you for your detailed answer. Is it possible to arrange 10 min consulmet chat? (paid if needed), i just have this bunch of question marks, which i'd like to solve, and unfortunately the web is yet to give me answers. Either way - thank you sir!

Comment: I'll be in touch :)

Comment: I'm going to spam this answer in order to create the chat.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid talking about GOT at a stuck answer

Comment: Please open up a chat!!

Comment: Is it suppose to be two ways comments in order to create one?

Comment: Check your email ;)

Comment: Haha - that's awesome!

Comment: Warren, i've send you a detailed question to your attached email that you told me to sent, Would love an answer for this - super excited! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @warrenm! Could you please also explain, what is the complexity of CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage? Do we actually perform any memory copy when converting CVPixelBuffer to the Metal texture?

Comment: @karama I wouldn't expect this function to perform a copy. Instead, it likely uses an API like `IOSurface` to share memory between the image and the texture.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest, barebones minimum code required to convert from a sample buffer produced by the video camera to a Metal texture:

```
@import UIKit;
@import AVFoundation;
@import CoreMedia;
#import <MetalKit/MetalKit.h>
#import <Metal/Metal.h>
#import <MetalPerformanceShaders/MetalPerformanceShaders.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MTKViewDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>  {
    NSString *_displayName;
    NSString *serviceType;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) SessionContainer *session;
@property (retain, nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *avSession;

@end;

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    MTKView *_metalView;

    id<MTLDevice> _device;
    id<MTLCommandQueue> _commandQueue;
    id<MTLTexture> _texture;

    CVMetalTextureCacheRef _textureCache;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice;
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t sessionQueue;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    _metalView = [[MTKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [_metalView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    _metalView.device = _device;
    _metalView.delegate = self;
    _metalView.clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1, 1, 1, 1);
    _metalView.colorPixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
    _metalView.framebufferOnly = NO;
    _metalView.autoResizeDrawable = NO;

    CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(NULL, NULL, _device, NULL, &_textureCache);

    [self.view addSubview:_metalView];

    self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL );

    if ([self setupCamera]) {
        [_avSession startRunning];
    }
}

- (BOOL)setupCamera {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    @try {
        NSError * error;

            _avSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
            [_avSession beginConfiguration];
            [_avSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

            // get list of devices; connect to front-facing camera
            self.videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
            if (self.videoDevice == nil) return FALSE;

            AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.videoDevice error:&error];
            [_avSession addInput:input];

            dispatch_queue_t sampleBufferQueue = dispatch_queue_create("CameraMulticaster", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

            AVCaptureVideoDataOutput * dataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
            [dataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
            [dataOutput setVideoSettings:@{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)}];
            [dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:sampleBufferQueue];

            [_avSession addOutput:dataOutput];
            [_avSession commitConfiguration]; 
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%s - %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, exception.description);
        return FALSE;
    } @finally {
        return TRUE;
    }

}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    {
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

        CVMetalTextureRef texture = NULL;
        CVReturn status = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm, width, height, 0, &texture);
        if(status == kCVReturnSuccess)
        {
            _metalView.drawableSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
            _texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture);
            _commandQueue = [_device newCommandQueue];
            CFRelease(texture);
        }
    }
}

- (void)drawInMTKView:(MTKView *)view {
    // creating command encoder
    if (_texture) {
        id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
        id<MTLTexture> drawingTexture = view.currentDrawable.texture;

        // set up and encode the filter
        MPSImageGaussianBlur *filter = [[MPSImageGaussianBlur alloc] initWithDevice:_device sigma:5];

        [filter encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:_texture destinationTexture:drawingTexture];

        // committing the drawing
        [commandBuffer presentDrawable:view.currentDrawable];
        [commandBuffer commit];
        _texture = nil;
    }
}

- (void)mtkView:(MTKView *)view drawableSizeWillChange:(CGSize)size {

}

@end
```